# How to I work with window.requestAnimationFrame and yet be able to change it's speed?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Is there a way to temporarily modify the speed of something with window.requestAnimationFrame in the middle of say, a classic Snake game?

See the following code:

```
class Game {

    constructor(snake) {
        this.snake = snake;
    }

    draw() {
        this.snake.slither()
        this.snake.draw()

    }

    start() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent); 
        let x = 8;
        interval = setInterval(this.draw.bind(this), 1000 / x);
    }

}
```

In the above example, if I wanted to temporarily change the speed, I would just change the interval speed, and then after setTimeOut, return the speed back to normal.

Comment: No time for an answer, but never assume that rAF will run at a constant rate across devices, it's not the case. For instance Chrome will make it run at the screen refresh rate, so if a user has a 240Hz gaming monitor, then your snake will go 4x faster for them than for the users using a 60Hz monitor. Quite unfair... So rather than doing `position.x ++`, you should calculate the delta time between two frames, and move your snake relative to this delta-time and its speed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, and for the best, you cannot change the speed of the `requestAnimationFrame` speed as it is calculated by the browser to ensure a good performance.

You can however, like you described yourself, change an interval speed. But setting `setInterval` doesn't allow the interval speed to be changed, unless being stopped and restarted. Alternatively you could use a function which uses `setTimeout` and calls itself after each timeout is being called.

The `setTimeout` should use a variable or property that is available in all function scopes to use and modify the `interval` rate.

```
let timeout = null;
let interval = 0;

function render() {
  // Render your animation.
}

function draw() {
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    draw();
  }, interval);
}

function stop() {
  if (timeout !== null) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}

function changeDrawSpeed(times) {
  interval = 100 * times;
}
```

```
draw();

setTimeout(changeDrawSpeed, 1000, 50);
setTimeout(changeDrawSpeed, 3000, 0);
```

Comment: No, you should still use it so that the rendering is being throttled to 60fps, but control the execution of `requestAnimationFrame` with a `setTimeout`. So you have a function that calls `requestAnimationFrame`, but only does that every n milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just forked and edited a bit a previous example of mine for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/2k81ya5q/

You can certainly write a routine to control your game frames, I have a small library for instance where I can do:

```
rafx.async({frame:0})
.animate(function(frames){
   let frame = ++frames.frame;
   if (!(frames % 3)) { //skip every third frame
     return frames;
   }
   //game logic here
}).until(function(frames){
    //return true to quit;
}).then(//whatever follows)
```

You can also pass additional variables that modify in-run-time how animation changes (frames or whatever).

https://github.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/RafX